# Android: child view outside of its parent doesn't respond to click events

Tags: android, parent-child, android-view, onclicklistener

For having effects I scale up the child view which cause child view to go out side of its parent view. I have a button in child view, it works before scaling but after scaling doesn't work. what is going wrong? see image below:

[image: button outside doesn't work]

for scaling child I use this code:

```
            childView.bringToFront();
            Animation a = new Animation() {
                @Override
                protected void applyTransformation(float t, Transformation trans) {
                    float scale = 1f * ( 1 - t ) + SCALE_UP_FACTOR * t;
                    childView.setScaleX(scale);
                    childView.setScaleY(scale);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            a.setDuration(ANIM_DURATION);
            a.setInterpolator(new Interpolator() {
                @Override
                public float getInterpolation(float t) {
                    t -= 1f;
                    return (t * t * t * t * t) + 1f; // (t-1)^5 + 1
                }
            });
            childView.startAnimation(a);
```

the parent is a `ViewPager` :

```
     <ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/invoice_list_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        />
```

Comment: Please provide your code in your activity or fragment and also the xml of your layout

Comment: Does the button respond if you tap on its original (unscaled) location when the view is scaled?

Comment: @Barend as I mentioned in question : "it works before scaling but after scaling doesn't work"

Comment: @Barend . I changed the image

Comment: @Ya Hoo did you find the solution? I got the same issue

Comment: no, I use another way to achieve desire effect

Comment: What is the point of this if the button is outside the visible window, the user can click on it?

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
final View grandParent = (View) childView.getParent().getParent();
grandParent.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Rect offsetViewBounds = new Rect();
        childView.getHitRect(offsetViewBounds);

        // After scaling you probably want to append your view to the new size.
        // in your particular case it probably could be only offsetViewBounds.right:
        // (animDistance - int value, which you could calculate from your scale logic)
        offsetViewBounds.right = offsetViewBounds.right + animDistance;

        // calculates the relative coordinates to the parent
        ((ViewGroup)parent).offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(childView, offsetViewBounds);
        grandParent.setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(offsetViewBounds, childView));
    }
});
```

Though I'm not sure whether it will work with `Animation`, but for scaling you could use something like that instead:

```
float scale = ...; // your scale logic

ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(childView, 
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", scale),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", scale));
animator.setDuration(ANIM_DURATION);
animator.start();
```

And pay attention to the line `android:clipChildren="false"` for your parent view in XML-file.

Comment: This won't work, because even tho you use the touch delegate, you cannot exceed the bounds of the parent views with a touchable area. meaning clicks won't be registered by the parent if they are done outside its view-bounds and therefore cant be forwarded to the button.

Comment: @Csharpest in that case you always can call grand parent instead of parent: 


```final View parent = (View) childView.getParent().getParent();```


I tested it. It works. Changed it in my answer.

Comment: Damn, i didnt know that, and i missed that out. You might even call your parent variable "grandParent" then :P. Thanks for the info

Comment: @Csharpest good point, changed my answer, now it's grandParent :) If my answer was useful, you can mark it as useful :)

Comment: How can i mark it as useful :D if u mean "accept" then im sorry, cause im not the author of the question